# Where are WP_Errors Saved

Tags: database, errors, debug

Hi it seems to be trivial question but it is the one I can not find an answer of. I am tweaking a wp site developed by somebody. They have used custom errors and they are getting errors by get_error_code(); but there is no place I could find where they have actually saved the errors. I want to customise the errors so is there a database table where the errors are saved in the wordpress database. Kindly advise thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `WP_Error` objects, or do you mean PHP errors in general?

Answer (score 1):

`WP_Error` kind of errors are a poor substitution for exception (something that php 4 didn't have IIRC), they are not actual software errors, and are not being kept in any log if the developer do not write code for it.

Comment: you mean they are self generated and there is no way I can check and modify the error messages on html form submission.

Comment: what does it mean "self generated"?  @Zeeshan